# How should the vowel/s represented by "yud yud" be pronounced outside of Yiddish?

Tags: talmud-gemara, grammar-dikduk, aramaic, yiddish, vowels-nekudot

אורייתא, ברייתא and היינו are just three common examples of Aramaic words found in Gemara which are commonly pronounced containing the 'ay' (/ai/ei) sound. Of course, this corresponds to Yiddish whose custodians even employ a special digraph: ײַ. The question is: are those words, and many others, being pronounced correctly?

I'll concede that I don't ask this question out of innocence and that I'm entertaining a hunch as to the correct answer to this question. Still, I'd love to hear what other people think before I share what I suspect.

Comment: I suppose your hunch is in line with your display name.

Comment: Well, to date I haven't heard anyone pronounce *that* 'bar urayn'. Yet.

Answer (score 5):

My fellow yeshiva bachur studied Aramaic intensely, and could hold a fluent conversation (if he had anybody to speak with). He said it should be אוֹרִייַתָא.